# useMutation hook error not corresponding with thrown error message on the server

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

`useMutation` hook error not corresponding with the thrown error  message on the server

The client error link log is correct `[GraphQL error]: Message: Authentication required., Location: undefined, Path: undefined`
client code error logging

```
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
      ),
    );

  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: from([errorLink, authLink, uploadLink,]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Client code: mutation/query

```js
const [signIn, { loading, error, data, networkStatus }] = useLazyQuery(
  PROFILE,
  { notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true }
);
```

Logging the error gives me this:

`Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400`

Server code:

```js
if (!user)
  throw new GraphQLError("Authentication required.", {
    extensions: { code: "UNAUTHORIZED" },
  });
```

Comment: Most of the time a 400 error means you're sending an invalid query/mutation from the client to the server. Test it in the sandbox first to validate it.

Comment: Yes, I test it... What I want is to get thrown an in the server when  not Authenticated and not attempting the user resolver

Comment: Not sure if I understand. You can throw an error in your mutation resolver rather than the user resolver. You can't throw an error in your context function. I'd suggest throwing an `AuthenticationError` (from 'apollo-server-errors' by the way.

Comment: a) Please post the code of your client error-handling link b) please add the code that logs the error returned by the hook c) your title mentions `useMutation`, but your second snippet shows `useLazyQuery`?

Comment: please add your useMutation code

Comment: You can't throw an error in your context function. I'd suggest throwing an AuthenticationError (from 'apollo-server-errors' by the way.  So how can detect token expiration and ask for an email & password in react ... Taking it that the user is trying to fetch, and his token is no longer recognised, throws an error at the top level. So that client will detect and move to login. Thank

Comment: Throw the Apollo AuthenticationError in your query on the server. In your client look for `error` being *truthy* and navigate to your login screen if you see an authentication error there.